# Element should be disable

Tags: selenium, robotframework, keyword

I want to check if elements aren't editable and are just read-only. For this 
I use `Element Should Be Disabled` keyword but, I'm having trouble when I run the test case.

When I run this test case:

```
SeleniumLibrary.Element Should Be Disabled    id=typeC
SeleniumLibrary.Element Should Be Disabled    id=TypeI
```

For this HTML code:

```html
<div _ngcontent-c10="">
  <label _ngcontent-c10="" class="radio-inline">
     <label _ngcontent-c10="" class="input-field">
        <input _ngcontent-c10="" formcontrolname="type" id="typeC" name="type" type="radio" value="C" class="ng-pristine ng-touched" disabled="">
            Company
      </label>
   </label>
  <label _ngcontent-c10="" class="radio-inline">
      <label _ngcontent-c10="" class="input-field">
        <input _ngcontent-c10="" formcontrolname="type" id="TypeI" name="type" type="radio" value="I" class="ng-pristine ng-touched" disabled="">
            Individual
      </label>
   </label>
 </div>
```

I have this error:

```
Element 'id=typeC' is enabled.
```

When I try:

```
SeleniumLibrary.Element Should Be Enabled    id=typeC
SeleniumLibrary.Element Should Be Enabled    id=TypeI
```

The error is:

```
Element 'id=typeC' is disabled.
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `typeC` and `TypeI` are only associated with a single element on the page?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, its only used on this element.

Comment: can you share url of html where you face this?

Answer (score 0):

Element Should Be Visible    //input[@id='typeC' and @disabled='']

Or

Element Should Be Visible    //input[@id='typeC' and not(@disabled='')]